# How do I make a recursive method which takes type List where the output is a different List?

Tags: java, list, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive method which takes a `List` of `Integer` and return a new `List` with only the positive numbers of the original `List`.

So here's what I've done

```
static List<Integer> positives(List<Integer> a) {
    if (a.getTail().isEmpty()) 
        return new List<Integer>(a.getHead(), new List<Integer>());

    if (a.getHead() - a.getHead() == 0) 
        new List<Integer>(a.getHead(), new List<Integer>());
        return positives(a.getTail());

    else
       return positives(a.getTail());
```

So when the head of the `List` is positive, it should add it to a new list and then the method loops. If the head isn't positive, it just loops. When the end of the `List` is reached, it should return the list containing the positive numbers.

I can tell that with my code currently that the `isEmpty()` statement returns a completely different list to the positive check statement which is where I'm going wrong. So I can't figure out how to return the list from the second if statement when the loop has reached the end of the `List`

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive?

Comment: It looks like you need a helper method.

Comment: What is the List implementation you use?

Comment: Unless this is a class project to learn recursion, this is a terrible technique.  As @Flo implied, this in no way requires recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way though not recursive would be using streams

```
List<Integer> posList = a.stream().filter(x -> x > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not insane and this is either a class project
or is a significantly dumbed-down version of something that legitimately
does "require" recursion,
here is an answer.

Hint: The method that is called by the client does not need to be the recursive method.

Some codelike stuff:

```
public class BlammyHoot
{
  public List<Integer> letsPretendRecursionIsRequired(final List<Integer> inputList)
  {
    final List<Integer> returnValue = new LinkedList<>();

    ... perform input validiation before entering the recursive method.

    theRecursiveMethod(inputList, returnValue);

    return returnValue;
  }

  private void theRecursiveMethod(
    final List<Integer> sourceList,
    final List<Integer> destinationList)
  {
    ... do your recursive thing here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential issues with this statement:

```
if (a.getTail().isEmpty()) 
    return new List<Integer>(a.getHead(), new List<Integer>());
```

First, we return `a.getHead()` without ever having tested if it's positive or negative.  Second, we're creating an extra `List` for no apparent reason.  Third, are we trying to instantiate an interface rather than a class?  In this `if`statement:

```
if (a.getHead() - a.getHead() == 0) 
    new List<Integer>(a.getHead(), new List<Integer>());
    return positives(a.getTail());
```

We're complicting the `a.getHead() >= 0` test for no obvious reason; we're again creating an extra `List`; we're creating new structure when we should be adding to the existing structure returned by `positives()`.

(Lacking `.getHead() and .getTail()`) Here's how I might go about this:

```
static List<Integer> positives(List<Integer> a) {
    List<Integer> non_negatives, tail = a.subList(1, a.size()); // tail = a.getTail()

    if (tail.isEmpty()) 
        non_negatives = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // need to create List to return
    else {
        non_negatives = positives(tail);
    }

    Integer head = a.get(0);  // head = a.getHead()

    if (head >= 0) 
            non_negatives.add(0, head);

    return non_negatives;
}
```